# Search text with javascript widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a Widget for an app that creates a search input and searches text from a div. The Widget creates the element and when the user runs the preview, the search is active and he can search for a text.

After i create the widget and the `input` is created, when i'm trying to search something, Chrome console says that the `searchTxt() is not a function`.

The goal is to pass the value of the input to `searchTxt` function, find the text inside the canvas div and highlight it. But i cant even return it in console.log.

Any suggestions ? Thank you in advance for any help.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lk533o8/)

Comment: Because `searchTxt()` is not a function,  but `_SWdgt().searchText()` is.

Comment: Tried that, but `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, edited my answer, [and fixed your demo fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lk533o8/10/)

1. Your button onclick called `search()`, there was no search.
2. You have to define your function by `window.funcname = function(){ ... }` because jsfiddle wraps that code in an on load.

So, I switched your onclick to call searcTxt and created the function properly and it works.
I also changed it to alert instead of console.log.

I don't know what the other javascript function is, but the code that makes sense is now working.

Comment: Well, open your javascript console on the page (F12 on the browser) and enter $("#srcTxt").val() there and see what you get.

Comment: Well, do you have anything in the input itself?  If you do `$("srcTxt").val("New Value")` does it put "New Value" in the input on the page?

Comment: Yea. Input `New Value` is ok.

Comment: Create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ - what you are saying does not make sense.

Comment: @nefeli That jsfiddle is failing because the button references a publically-accessible `search` function that isn't defined.

Comment: @Katana314 thanks for the clearance. Any suggestion on that ? I'm not a javascript ninja. I haven't worked with js since college

Comment: @nefeli I'd suggest you write a brief `search()` method in the JSFiddle to use your widget and demonstrate the error, but it kinda looks like it has some outside dependencies of its own - `myWdg`, something to call `createElement`, etc. Is this some sort of framework plugin you're building? JSFiddle lets you load certain frameworks like JQuery automatically through its sidebar, if that helps.

Comment: @Katana314 i included the system.js in External Resources of JSFiddle

Comment: OK, check my edits to my answer and the new fiddle is linked there.